# Subclass NameError in Ruby in the Same File

Tags: ruby, class, syntax, subclass

I'm having a bit of problem with Ruby. I'm trying to make a class that simulates a battle between tribes.

```
class Tribe
   def initialize(name, population)
     @name = name
     @population = population
  end
   def attack(opponent)
    opponent.population -= @population
    puts "#{@name} attacks #{opponent.name}!"
    puts "#{opponent.name}'s population is #{opponent.population}!"
   end

class Hero < Tribe
    def initialize(name, population)
        @name = name
        @population = population
    end
end
class Opposer < Tribe
    def initialize(name, population)
        @name = name
        @population = population
    end
   end
 end

  chouli = Tribe::Hero.new("Chouli", 26)
  arials = Tribe::Opposer.new("Arials", 60)
```

But when I run the code, I get:

```
person.rb:28:in '<main>': uninitialized constant Hero
```

### EDIT

Okay. I fixed my code using acsmith's suggestion. Here's the new code:

```
class Tribe
   def initialize(name, population)
     @name = name
     @population = population
  end
   def attack(opponent)
    opponent.population -= @population
    puts "#{@name} attacks #{opponent.name}!"
    puts "#{opponent.name}'s population is #{opponent.population}!"
   end

class Hero < Tribe
    def initialize(name, population)
        @name = name
        @population = population
    end
end
class Opposer < Tribe
    def initialize(name, population)
        @name = name
        @population = population
    end
   end
 end

  chouli = Tribe::Hero.new("Chouli", 26)
  arials = Tribe::Opposer.new("Arials", 60)
```

So, the new error is:

```
person.rb:8:in 'attack': undefined method 'population' for #          <Opposer:0x0000000 @name="Arials", @population=60> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: You're defining your subclasses in the middle of your `Tribe` class.

Comment: There's some seriously ugly indenting going on here. Can you clear that up? There's at least one `end` missing.

Comment: Sorry, my code formatter is acting weird.

Comment: The formatting is a little confusing, but I don't fundamentally disagree with putting `Hero` and `Opposer` within the `Tribe` namespace. It should work just fine if you change the calls to what I wrote in my answer below.

Comment: @JacobSanning I ran your updated code and everything worked fine for me, the syntax seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, `Hero` and `Opposer` are being defined within the namespace of `Tribe`. This means that your calls should actually be:

```
chouli = Tribe::Hero.new("Chouli", 26)
arials = Tribe::Opposer.new("Arials", 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subclasses are currently being defined inside of your `Tribe` class declaration, instead of being defined after the `Tribe` definition. This is how your sample code should be written:

```
class Tribe
  def initialize(name, population)
    @name = name
    @population = population
  end

  def attack(opponent)
    opponent.population -= @population
    puts "#{@name} attacks #{opponent.name}!"
    puts "#{opponent.name}'s population is #{opponent.population}!"
  end
end

class Hero < Tribe
  def initialize(name, population)
    @name = name
    @population = population
  end
end

class Opposer < Tribe
  def initialize(name, population)
    @name = name
    @population = population
  end
end

chouli = Hero.new("Chouli", 26)
arials = Opposer.new("Arials", 60)
```